# Ubuntu 20.04 backlight problem, only boots from recovery mode

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, brightness, intel, backlight

As a new Ubuntu user, I am facing a problem with my backlight.
After succesfully **dual booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on my HP ENVY x360 15-es0570nd (Intel core i7 processor and NVIDIA grapics card)**, everything worked fine exept for brightness controll.

I tried to fix this by following the steps provided here: https://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/. (ls /sys/class/backlight/ showed (only) intel_backlight by then)

However, after creating and editing the "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf" file, there were several glitches in my screen after normal boot. Since I had created this file, with a subsequent display fail, I decided to remove the file. (at the moment it is no longer present at my xorg.conf directory)

Since then my **/sys/class/backlight/ folder is empty**, whereas before it showed intel_backlight! I am not able to boot normally into Ubuntu (I get a black screen), **I can only boot through recovery mode**. (although I also get this first line stating: "/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80:/etc/default/rcS: no such file or directory")

I tried several things to re-install my backlight (but without succes)

Can anyone please help me to fix this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Install 21.10 instead. Your hardware is newer than the release you installed and that is never a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for you time ChanganAuto, will do that!

Answer (score 0):

to me it happened after trying to install a appimage with the package FUSE.
if thats the case boot into recovery mode and `apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal` or `apt install ubuntu-desktop` will solve the issue